# Formatting dates to another format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server. The columns `SAMPLDATE` and `RECDATE` contains dates, but they are in `yymmdd` format. I will like to format these columns to show the dates in `ddmmyy` instead, how can I achieve this? Please help.

I have searched the web but couldn't find a simple example to help. Please see the sample of my table attached.

[Sample of the table is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UK8QS.png)

[image]

Comment: Those don't look like dates. They look like varchar or ints. Using the correct datatype is crucial to a good database.

Comment: Yes, please look at the column type and check that it is a date or datetime of some sort. If not, as @SeanLange mentioned, MSSQL doesn't know they are dates and there are various reasons that is non-ideal. You might have to use the "DATEPART" function and slice the existing data to convert to real MSSQL "date" then use FORMAT as below.

Comment: Assuming they're string... left aligned column... `Update TableName set SamplDate = RIGHT(SAMPLDate,2)+substr(samplDate,3,2)+left(SamplDate,2)` If you EVER need to do math on it, store it as a number
If you'll NEVER do math on it store it as string
If it needs to do both, you need two columns
Except for dates... store dates as dates period and use date functions on them... not string {shudder} functions!
and AutoIncrements can be numbers (though we should never do math on them) (Copied from my profile)

Comment: Ok why?  This is character data.  As such any systems making reference to it may expect it to be in YYMMDD format.  By switching it you could corrupt those systems.  If this is a new system; we all highly recommend changing your columns to be date datatypes.  standards for dates actually state to use YYYYMMDD when using character data dates (not recommended) so it sorts easier and you can do < > date compares easier..  If you switch and want to find   horses > 180101  and you search for > 010118 you're going to get wrong data back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work assuming you have a consistent date mask on your VARCHAR column:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,  
               SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,5,2) + '/' +
               SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,3,2) + '/' + 
               SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,1,2))
```

This will convert your `VARCHAR` to a `DATETIME`

And now add the format:

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime,  
               SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,5,2) + '/' +
               SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,3,2) + '/' + 
               SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,1,2)), 'ddMMyy')
```

Performing the `CONVERT` only makes sense if you truly want to be dealing with dates.  If you only care about the format then simply rearrange using `SUBSTRING()`

```
SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,5,2) + '/' +
SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,3,2) + '/' + 
SUBSTRING(SAMPLDATE,1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh213505(v=sql.120).aspx) to convert the dates.

`SELECT FORMAT(SAMPLDATE, 'ddMMyy')`